# unable to convert an Observable into a ConnectableObservable

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

I have a `BehaviorSubject`. I am trying to convert its `Observable` into a `ConnectableObservable` but I am getting error `publishBehaviour` is not a function. What am I doing wrong?

> this.questionsArray$.publishBehavior is not a function TypeError:
>   this.questionsArray$.publishBehavior is not a function

The code snippet is

```ts
private questionsArraySubject: BehaviorSubject<Result>; 
questionsArray$: Observable<Result>;
questionsArrayConnectable$:ConnectableObservable<Result>;

this.questionsArraySubject = new BehaviorSubject<Result>(new Result('initial',{}));

// create Observable. Other components can subcribe to it now to get notifications/values
this.questionsArray$ = this.questionsArraySubject.asObservable(); 
this.questionsArrayConnectable$ = this.questionsArray$.publishBehavior(new Result('initial',{}))
```

Comment: With RxJS 6 you have to use the `pipe` syntax `questionsArray$.pipe(publishBehavior(..))`

Comment: Thanks. happy to accept your answer. I did `questionsArray$: ConnectableObservable<Result>;` and then `this.questionsArray$ = (this.questionsArraySubject.asObservable()).pipe(publish()) as ConnectableObservable<Result>;`. After subscribing in the component, I used `connect`

Comment: You don't have to use `asObservable()` in this case as Subjects are Observables.